# Using a past participle as an object

Tags: grammaticality

I've found the usage of **"past participle as an object"** in  a dictionary.
But I wanted to know in which cases I could use a past participle as an object.

Can I build up a sentence like this?

> He makes me **shone**

.

Comment: Please provide an example of the construction you are asking about, or quote the text you found in the dictionary. Also, please clarify the question ("With ' past participle ' should it use ?" - should it be *which*?)

Comment: You can't *make* an object be a past participle, the object has to *want* to be a past participle. *(Sorry - that was a lame joke, not grammar advice.)*

Answer (score 1):

When you say *make* in the sense of *to cause/force to do*, I think it takes a bare infinitive, not an object.

> He makes me shine, He made me shine.

---

Past participles, when not used as a linking/auxillary/helping verb with a *have* or *be*, are generally *modifiers*.

One thing you can do with modifiers in English is use them as nouns, if the surrounding context supports strongly implying the noun and you are talking about a large group of things.  For example.

> I separated all the clothes by color, then I put all the red {clothes} in the laundry.  (There's a lot of clothes).
>
> The evil spirit cast a spell, and now the damned {spirits} walk the earth.

Doesn't apply to your example but that's when you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

"Just go to the hotel reception and make yourself known (to the receptionist)."

Check out these references:

1. **[Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/make-yourself-known)**
2. **[Google Books: Ref #1](https://books.google.gr/books?id=9x0AAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA256-IA4&dq=%22make+it+known%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22make%20it%20known%22&f=false)**
3. **[Google Books: Ref #2](https://books.google.gr/books?id=iuhhAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA405&dq=%22make+it+known%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjah97Ahe3MAhVIAcAKHchmC8UQ6AEIIjAC#v=onepage&q=%22make%20it%20known%22&f=false)**

Comment: Please add a little more contents to your answer. An answer purely based on external link references isn't quite enough.